# Python delete dictionary items with same values

Tags: python-3.x

How would I remove dictionary items that have different keys but identical values? I am sure there a better way than my novice algorithm...?

**Example:** (abends with error "*dictionary changed size during iteration*")

*The goal of this example is to remove either 'car_id' or 'truck_id' from dict.*

```
key_fields_obj = {}
key_fields_obj['car_id'] = 'bob'
key_fields_obj['bike_id'] = 'sam'
key_fields_obj['truck_id'] = 'bob' #goal: remove this one, so left with only car_id and bike_id

for item in key_fields_obj:
    tst = key_fields_obj[item]
    for comp in key_fields_obj:
        if item == comp:
            continue
        cmp = key_fields_obj[comp]
        if cmp == tst:
            del key_fields_obj[comp]

print(key_fields_obj)
```

Comment: Does it matter which key is kept? What would the logic be for deciding whether to keep `'car_id'` or `'bike_id'`, or does it just not matter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a new dict with values as key and key as values, then perform the same again on new dict.

```
>>> key_fields_obj = {key_fields_obj[key]: key for key in key_fields_obj}
>>> key_fields_obj
{'bob': 'truck_id', 'sam': 'bike_id'}
>>>
>>> key_fields_obj = {key_fields_obj[key]: key for key in key_fields_obj}
>>> key_fields_obj
{'truck_id': 'bob', 'bike_id': 'sam'}
```

Comment: This is genius, mate. Very clever. Thanks.

Comment: This will work for OP's situation, but it will fail if there are any unhashable values in the original `dict`. Lists, for example.

Answer (score 2):

```
seem_values = set()

for key, value in list(key_fields_obj.items()):
   if value in seem_values:
       del key_fields_obj[key]
   else:
       seem_values.add(value)
```

Comment: This is almost great -- but it loses the keys of the unique value items. Otherwise, it *does* return a list of unique values. But can it return an object that retains the original keys?